# Spring boot mongo repository custom implementation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

hi i followed [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) instruction, and i have custom method implementation like this:

interface

```
interface ProfileMongoRepositoryCustom  {
  fun addCourse(id: String)
}
```

Implementation

```
class ProfileMongoRepositoryCustomImpl(
  @Autowired val mongoOperations: MongoOperations,

  ) : ProfileMongoRepositoryCustom {
  override fun addCourse(id: String) {
   // some implementation
  }
}
```

mongo repo

```
@Repository
interface ProfileMongoRepository : MongoRepository<Profile, String>, ProfileMongoRepositoryCustom {
  fun findByEmail(email: String): Profile?
  fun findByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String): Profile?
}
```

when i run the program, it shows an error:
 `No property addCourse found for type Profile!`

it seems like the implementation is not read by the application because if i put the implementation in the same module and package with the interface it worked, my module structure is:

- -- project-app (main class)
- -- project-repo (this is where mongo repo and custom interface belong)
- -- project-repo-impl (this is where my custom implementaion belong)

Answer (score 0):

Basically just remove "Mongo" on your repository custom interface name

Rename
`ProfileMongoRepositoryCustom` to `ProfileRepositoryCustom`

also
`ProfileMongoRepositoryCustomImpl` to `ProfileRepositoryCustomImpl`

Reference from https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html (section: Adding custom behavior to single repositories)